# Strange memory usage pattern in C# Windows Form app

Tags: c#, oracle, memory-leaks, odp.net, perfmon

I am trying to understand what is going on in app written in C#. Below are several images taken from Performance Monitor. The blue line is #Bytes in all Heaps. The green line is Large Object Heap Size. I start the app and log me in. The app remains idle. The first image shows that LOH increases for some reason and then drops. A pattern is very clear. What is responsible for such behavior?

[image]

More. I do some heavy processing starting in A (see image below) using an Oracle Database through ODP.NET. After that the app remains idle again. The LOH does not drop. Instead it keeps increasing for some reason. Note that the application is idle. It is just open in my desktop. I am not even interacting with it.

[image]

Memory keeps increasing (each image represents 1:15:00).

[image]

After more than 2 hours suddenly it decreases and after while it starts increasing/decreasing again (see below) as in the first image. All the time app is idle. What is going on? Is it a memory leak? I don't think so. We profiled the app and couldn't find anything. Also the LOH increases without any activity. There is no open connection with the Oracle Database. Can ODP.NET be the culprit?

[image]

Comment: Don't really beleive that someone can help you with this. Too project specific stuff.

Comment: We are using a profiler and we couldn't spot anything unusual. The point is: something is going on under GC. Why memory allocation increases if the application is idle and why it decreases suddenly. If I just log me in, the app shows a pattern of allocation/deallocation that does not make sense. What is doing it?

Comment: Start with a known baseline. Create a trivial Winforms project that does nothing but make a form. Run it and measure its memory usage. Do you get the same weird behaviour? Then the problem isn't in your code; something weird is going on. You can then investigate what that is without worrying about it being something in your code. Do you instead get expected behaviour from the trivial program? Then something is different in the idle time processing of your code and the trivial winforms project. What that might be, only you can possibly know.

Comment: The up and down behavior of the first picture starts just after I log me in. So it starts just after a connection is made to the Oracle database, a stored procedure is executed and the connection closed. Nothing more is done and the application remains idle. As I said we suspect that ODP.Net is the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem definitely is due ODP.NET. If I disable the connection pool the problem does not manifest. For each connection ODP.NET seems to create 2 threads and at 3 minutes interval (as seen in the images) ODP.NET does some housekeeping but for some reason allocates memory that are not released right away.

It is easy to reproduce. Just create a simple app that when a button is pressed a connection to an Oracle database is open and a stored procedure is executed. You will notice the pattern of the first image. The pattern of the other images is due the number of connections created by the app.